# FFmpeg - combine 2 commands

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 2 commands as listed below.

**Add intro image to a video**

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -framerate 10 -t 3 -i intro.png -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:0] [1:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=0" -c:v libx264 -crf 23 videoWithIntro.mp4
```

**Add watermark to video**

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -i watermark_color.png -filter_complex "overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/2"  videoWithWatermark.mp4
```

I was wondering is it possible to combine these into the 1 command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -framerate 10 -t 3 -i intro.png -i video.mp4 -i watermark_color.png -filter_complex "[0][1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[v];[v][2]overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/2"  videoWithWatermark.mp4
```

I assume your videos don't have audio, else use

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -framerate 10 -t 3 -i intro.png -i video.mp4 -i watermark_color.png -f lavfi -t 3 -i anullsrc -filter_complex "[0][1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[v];[v][2]overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/2;[3][1]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1"  videoWithWatermark.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks @Mulvya - that video adds the watermark to the intro image. Is it possible to just add the watermark to the video part and not the first few seconds intro?

Comment: The overlay should be placed before the concat. overlay input should be `[1][2]` and output pad `[v]`. concat input should be `[v][1]` and remove output pad `[v]`.

Comment: Is this the filter I should go with? "[1][2]overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/2[v];[v][1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0"

Comment: Sorry, it should be `"[1][2]overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/2‌​[v];[0][v]concat=n=2‌​:v=1:a=0"`

Comment: thanks yeah the order is now correct however the video starts along with the intro

Comment: would you know how to show intro.png for 3 seconds and then start the video as part of the command mentioned above?

Comment: Unfortunately it plays the video straight away.

Comment: Is that what you were after? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9af08c808da58d0620ff80f2ffc43637

Comment: No error seen. You can change the image's framerate to 25 to avoid frame drops.

Comment: tried that but the audio from the video is coming through on the intro image. Should I just convert an image to a video, add watermark to the video and concat the 2 videos in 3 separate commands?

Comment: If you have audio, you should adapt the 2nd command in my answer!

Comment: I want to remove the audio. The problem is that the video is starting during the intro. Can we stop this from happening? I want the intro to start - play for 3 seconds - then the video plays with the watermark

Comment: Add `-an` to remove the audio.

Comment: Yes I have done that and the video is still playing before the intro ends. My video is 10 seconds long. If i make the intro show for 8 seconds - only 2 seconds of the video remain

Comment: By video, you mean the visual and not the audio from that file? That sounds weird. Show the report from the latest command.

Comment: correct yes - I do not care about the audio. Here is the report https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e5b45f3dab775063bbee49e17a66df69

Comment: In that run, you've stopped execution at `-t 10` and none of the main video should have come through, as intro image is 10 secs long. You should keep image framerate to same as video rate else video will have many dropped frames. Other than that, I don't see any issues other than "[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000019ef5970360] st: 0 edit list: 1 Missing key frame while searching for timestamp: 1000"  But no further warning related to that.

Comment: Apolgoies - I removed the stopping of the execution and ensured the frame rates were the same - here is the updated report https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dfb5c1c79550a1aad7c257d023acbd58

Comment: Don't remove the image's duration! Add `[0]setsar=1[pre]` just after the overlay and change inputs of concat to `[pre][v]`

Comment: to be this is it? -filter_complex "[1][2]overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/2[v][0]setsar=1[pre];[pre][v]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0"

Comment: `"[1][2]overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/2‌​,setsar=1[v];[0]setsar=1[pre];‌​[pre][v]concat=n=2:v‌​=1:a=0"`

Comment: thank you - that appears to have done the trick - my final command is ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -framerate 25 -t 3 -i 1920x1080_intro.png -i DSC_0002.MOV -i watermark_color.png -report -an -filter_complex "[1][2]overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/2,setsar=1[v];[0]setsar=1[pre];[pre][v]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0" ../testing/videoWithIntroAndWatermark.mp4

Answer (score 0):

The final command to get this working correctly is as follows
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -framerate 25 -t 3 -i 1920x1080_intro.png -i DSC_0002.MOV -i watermark_color.png -report -an -filter_complex "[1][2]overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/2,setsar=1[v];[0]setsar=1[pre];[pre][v]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0" ../testing/videoWithIntroAndWatermark.mp4