# How to Combine two ffmpeg commands

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i input.txt -pix_fmt yuv420p -y ouput.mp4 -vf alphaextract c_mask.mp4

ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -i output_mask.mp4 -filter_complex “[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih[int];[int][1:v]overlay=W/2:0” ouput1.mp4
```

Comment: Did you look at other similar questions like these https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bffmpeg%5D+combine+commands?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FFmpeg - combine 2 commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47652586/ffmpeg-combine-2-commands)

Answer (score 0):

On mac or linux, use &&

ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i input.txt -pix_fmt yuv420p -y ouput.mp4 -vf alphaextract c_mask.mp4 && ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -i output_mask.mp4 -filter_complex “[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih[int];[int][1:v]overlay=W/2:0” ouput1.mp4

Be careful to not use sames names of files  :-)